# Conditional Performance of Matching Expression in Gawk

Tags: awk, match

I'm using gawk to match database entries (simple text file, "fields" separated with ::, one line = one record).  I have up to 8 variables I want to match, but the variables are based on user input, and don't necessarily exist/ are empty.  My logical operator is "AND" (&&).  I only want to perform a match for a particular variable if the variable exists, so that an empty variable does not return a "false" for the entire search.

---

For example, my variables are "date" and "reps".  I've tried:

```
{ if ( date ) { $2 ~ date } && if ( reps ) { $3 ~ reps }}
```

and I've also tried:

```
{ if ( date ) { $2 ~ date; && if ( reps ) $3 ~ reps }}
```

but the "&&" gives a syntax error (there may be other problems, too, of course).

---

How do I (1) perform a conditional match and (2) how to I string several of those together?

__

Follow up: from answers received so far (thank you!) I can tell I didn't state my logical requirements clearly. What I'm trying to achieve on an field basis is: if the variable exists and matches, select the record; but if the variable does not exist, ignore it as a test condition.  What I don't want to happen is when the variable does not exist, it still gets used as a test condition and results in the record not getting selected.  (Also, I'm not concerned about the variable existing and not matching.)  For an entire record, I want to use all existing variables in a cumulative basis.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. Based on what you've told us so far the right solution will be full field string matches on `::`-separated fields, not partial record regexp matches as you're currently trying to do, but without seeing sample input/output that's just a guess, as would any proposed solution be.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like

```bash
awk '
    # start by accepting all records
    { filter = 1 }
    
    # then, individually, see if any conditions fail
    filter && date && $2 !~ date { filter = 0 } 
    filter && reps && $3 !~ reps { filter = 0 } 
    # ...
    
    # then print the record if it has passed all the conditions
    filter
'
```

add in your mechanism to pass variables into awk.

You can string them together into one giant condition, but readability suffers

```
if (date && $2 ~ date && reps && $3 ~ reps && ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'yourfs' -v date="$DATE" -v reps="$REPS" '
    BEGIN{ if(!date || !reps) exit } 
    $1 ~ date && $2 ~ reps
' file
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P  if you read the question you will understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I(...)perform a conditional match

Take look at so-called ternary operator condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse, consider following example, let say you have `file.txt` as follows

```
0 abc
1 abc
0 def
1 def
```

and 1st column determines if check is to be made and check is *2nd columnd is abc* then you can do

```
awk '$1?$2=="abc":1' file.txt
```

which will give

```
0 abc
1 abc
0 def
```

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*